# C++ После выполнения одной функции execl, не выполняются другие

Tags: c++, linux, posix

Стоит задача: запустить 4 процесса системными вызовами: execl, execlp, execv, execvp; вывести идентификаторы этих процессов и закрыть их в обратном порядке.

Мой код:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Путь к выполняемому процессу
    auto firstPath = "/home/artem/CLionProjects/first_proc/cmake-build-debug/first_proc";
    auto secondPath = "/home/artem/CLionProjects/second_proc/cmake-build-debug/second_proc";

    execl(firstPath, "Функция execl" ,"Лабораторная", "работа", "№", "4", NULL);
    execlp(secondPath, "Лаба", "4", NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Почему получается так, что после выполнения `execl` все, что стоит ниже нее не выполняется? Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно делать так: сначала создать новый процесс и потом уже в нем вызывать  `execvp`:

```
bool launch(const char* path, const char* arg)
{
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        return false;       
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        //Дочерний процесс
        execvp(path, arg);
        _exit(72);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Это схематичный пример, подробней можно посмотреть в библиотеке POCO

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что функции семейства `exec*` замещают текущий исполняемый образ вновь запущенным. То есть, после выполнения первой `execl` вашей программы больше не существует, так как она замещается той которую вы запустили!

Как это исправить? А вот в этом и состоит суть лабораторной работы № 4.